# How to get full stackTrace

Tags: java, stack-trace

I have an unexpected error which creates stackTrace with very much lines and different libraries inside. If to read it since top till bottom, It's possible to see every method which is called except 2-3 first method. It looks like

```
//Pseudo code
method1_1(){
method2();
}

method1_2(){
method2();
}

method1_3(){
method2();
}


method2(){
method3();
}

method3(){
method4();
}

method4(){
method5();
}

method5(){
method6();
}
```

StackTrace shows only 3-6 methods but it doesn't show the second and which of first one call out this second? How can I know it? The program is big and logs are writing every 0,1-0,001 second. That's why take logging for every method is not good. I can't model the error, it only happens. I need to know what method throws that error. There are 6 first methods in the example, but there are much more.

**P.S.** trace looks like that

```html
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.dao.impl.UserDaoServiceImpl.updateUser(UserDaoServiceImpl.java:418)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.dao.impl.UserDaoServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8732584e.invoke(<generated>)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.dao.impl.UserDaoServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c376b217.updateUser(<generated>)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor936.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy564.updateUser(Unknown Source)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.mobile.utils.Class2.method3(Class2.java:58)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.mobile.utils.beans.Class3.method2(Class3.java:177)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at com.company.smx.data.mobile.utils.beans.Class3.lambda$method1$57(Class3.java:117)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
INFO   | 2019/04/11 14:23:20 |  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

`com.company.smx.data.mobile.utils.beans.Class3.lambda$method1$57(Class3.java:117)` it's the 3rd method of pseudocode, and which 1st and 2nd, I need to know

**UPD**
I call my 1st method through REST API, so it looks like

```
public interface RestService {

@GET
@Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
@Path(value = "/rest/method1")
ResultResponse method1 (@PathParam("id") String id);
}

public class RestServiceImpl implements RestService {

method1_1(String id){
method2();
}
//and other pseudo code

}
```

As I said before, I can find, also with @Common Man 's help the only method till the 3rd method, because after that I have only

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: can you put a breakpoint and step through where this is happening? maybe you can get more info out of it either

Comment: Unfortunately,I can't. It uses async everywhere like CompleteFuture, any reflection and etc. and as I wrote, it's a lot of logs in second. I can not guess when it would happen to catch breakpoint

Comment: Your Stack Trace is completely fine.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? It shouldn't be tried? And if my trace is fine, how to know which of "first " method call me 3rd, 4th and etc methods?

Comment: @Dred, i undeleted it, i have mentioned a link in my Answer, it is worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void printLongerTrace(Throwable t){
    for(StackTraceElement e: t.getStackTrace())
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

this would print each line of the Stacktrace, there will be no  `12...more`

Most probably this might not be the answer, but it is worth a look: https://coderanch.com/t/442321/java/full-stacktrace

Comment: I'll try it in 1 hour, thank you anyway for a chance )

Comment: i don't care for down-votes till it helps to learn , peace out :)

Comment: Hmm, that method shows every methods but till ThreadWorker. Is there any chance to know, which method force that worker do work?

Comment: It means, that from my snippet in Question, I can't see any method before line `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)`